# Resolvent for Neumann Laplacian operator

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

I want to find the resolvent for the Laplacian with Neumann boundary conditions:
$$D(A)=\{f\in W^{2,1}(0,1):f'(0)=f'(1)=0\},\quad f\mapsto Af:=f''. $$

I know that $0$ is an eigenvalue with eigenspace spanned by the constant one function. I need to compute the resolvent $R(\lambda, A):=(\lambda-A)^{-1}$ for $\lambda<0$ which are in the resolvent set of $A$.

**My try 1:** Let $f\in L^1(0,1)$ and $R(\lambda,A)f=g$. Then $f=(\lambda-A)g=\lambda g - g''$. Therefore $$
\begin{align*}\int_0^1 f^2(y)\, dy &= \lambda \int_0^1g(y)f(y)dy-\int_0^1f(y)g''(y)\, dy\\
&= \lambda \int_0^1g(y)f(y)dy+\int_0^1 f'(y)g'(y)\, dy\\
&=\lambda \int_0^1g(y)f(y)dy+ f'(1)g(1)-f'(0)g(0)-\int f''(y)g(y)\, dy.
\end{align*}$$

However, I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Any reference where the resolvent is explicitly computed would also be sufficient.

**Edit:**

**My try 2:** I tried to solve by variation of parameters and would appreciate if someone verifies it:

Let $\lambda\in (-\infty,0)\cap \rho(A)$ and $\mu=-\lambda$. The solution of the auxiliary equation is $g_c(x) = A \cos\sqrt{\mu}x + B\sin \sqrt{\mu}x$ and the Wronskian is $\sqrt{\mu}$. By variation of parameters: $$\sqrt{\mu}g_p(x)= \cos \sqrt{\mu} x\int_0^x \sin \sqrt{\mu} t f(t)\, dt-\sin \sqrt{\mu} x \int_0X\cos \sqrt{\mu} t f(t)\, dt.$$
So the solution is $$g(x)=A \cos\sqrt{\mu}x + B\sin \sqrt{\mu}x+\frac{1}{\sqrt \mu}\left(\cos \sqrt{\mu} x\int_0^x \sin \sqrt{\mu} t f(t)\, dt-\sin \sqrt{\mu} x \int_0^x\cos \sqrt{\mu} t f(t)\, dt \right).$$
Differentiating:
$$g'(x)=-\sin \sqrt{\mu} x\left(A \sqrt{\mu} + \int_0^x \sin \sqrt{\mu} t f(t)\, dt\right)+\cos\sqrt{\mu} x\left(B \sqrt{\mu} -\int_0^x \cos\sqrt{\mu} tf(t)\, dt\right).$$

Using $g'(0)=0$, we get $B=0$ and using $g'(1)=0$, we get

$$A=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu}} \int_0^1 \sin \sqrt{\mu} t f(t)\, dt.$$

Thus $$R(\lambda,A)f=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu}}\left(\cos \sqrt{\mu} x\int_x^1 \sin \sqrt{\mu} f(t)\, dt -\sin \sqrt{\mu} x\int_0^x \cos \sqrt{\mu} t f(t)\, dt\right).$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially what you are asking is how to solve the inhomogenous ODE
$$g''-\lambda g=f$$
subject to Neumann boundary conditions. For this I suggest you use **variation of parameters**, which will eventually give you an expression for $g$ in terms of $f$ and the solutions of the homogenous equation $g''-\lambda g=0$. Here are [two](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/VariationofParameters.aspx) [sources](https://www.12000.org/my_notes/ODE_using_green_function/index.htm#x1-40001.2) for this technique, the first more applied the second with some proofs. You may also consult an ODE textbook.

Comment: I tried doing it by the method you suggested. Can you check it?

Comment: It looks right to me! To be absolutely sure you could verify that it solves the ODE, but the fundamental solutions and Wronskian are correct so the solution should be as well.

Comment: Can you look at my [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4075160/904807)?