# Resolvent for Laplace operator (periodic boundary)

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, boundary-value-problem

I want to find the resolvent for the Laplacian with periodic boundary conditions:
$$D(A)=\{f\in W^{2,1}(0,1):f(0)=f(1) \text{ and }f'(0)=f'(1)\},\quad f\mapsto Af:=f''. $$

I know that $0$ is an eigenvalue with eigenspace spanned by the constant one function. I need to compute the resolvent $R(\lambda, A):=(\lambda-A)^{-1}$ for $\lambda<0$ which are in the resolvent set of $A$.

**My try:** I tried to solve by variation of parameters.

Let $\lambda\in (-\infty,0)\cap \rho(A)$ and $\mu=-\lambda$. The solution of the auxiliary equation is $g_c(x) = A \cos\sqrt{\mu}x + B\sin \sqrt{\mu}x$ and the Wronskian is $\sqrt{\mu}$. By variation of parameters: $$\sqrt{\mu}g_p(x)= \cos \sqrt{\mu} x\int_0^x \sin \sqrt{\mu} t f(t)\, dt-\sin \sqrt{\mu} x \int_0X\cos \sqrt{\mu} t f(t)\, dt.$$
So the solution is $$g(x)=A \cos\sqrt{\mu}x + B\sin \sqrt{\mu}x+\frac{1}{\sqrt \mu}\left(\cos \sqrt{\mu} x\int_0^x \sin \sqrt{\mu} t f(t)\, dt-\sin \sqrt{\mu} x \int_0^x\cos \sqrt{\mu} t f(t)\, dt \right).$$
Differentiating:
$$g'(x)=-\sin \sqrt{\mu} x\left(A \sqrt{\mu} + \int_0^x \sin \sqrt{\mu} t f(t)\, dt\right)+\cos\sqrt{\mu} x\left(B \sqrt{\mu} -\int_0^x \cos\sqrt{\mu} tf(t)\, dt\right).$$

Using boundary conditions we get $$A=A \cos\sqrt{\mu} + B\sin \sqrt{\mu}+\frac{1}{\sqrt \mu}\left(\cos \sqrt{\mu} \int_0^1 \sin \sqrt{\mu} t f(t)\, dt-\sin \sqrt{\mu}  \int_0^1\cos \sqrt{\mu} t f(t)\, dt \right)$$

and
$$\cos\sqrt{\mu} \left(B \sqrt{\mu} -\int_0^1 \cos\sqrt{\mu} tf(t)\, dt\right)=-\sin \sqrt{\mu} \left(A \sqrt{\mu} + \int_0^1 \sin \sqrt{\mu} t f(t)\, dt\right)+\cos\sqrt{\mu} \left(B \sqrt{\mu} -\int_0^1 \cos\sqrt{\mu} tf(t)\, dt\right).$$

**How do I solve for $A$ and $B$?** Any reference where the resolvent is computed explicitly is also appreciated.

**Edit:** Is there another approach to this question which I can try?